# Lenovo laptop v330 15IKB BIOS reboot loop

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop, reboot, firmware

> **Important:** I can't pass the stage of rebooting: no BIOS settings, boot order, anything; hence no access to any OS or software utility.

I updated my Lenovo laptop v330 15IKB BIOS firmware from the official page of Lenovo, using its installer utility (Windows 10). The software identifies the model and shows the firmware/drivers available for it, lets you choose what to install and then installs it.

After the installation the computer rebooted, but it got stuck in an infinite loop of *instant* rebooting.

What do I mean by instant? I can see the Lenovo logo for about 2 seconds, then reboots. I can't access the BIOS, it doesn't respond to the keyboard (<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Supr</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and any combination of keys I could think of or found on the net). It's like it doesn't even get to the point of reading the keyboard.

- I disconnected and reconnected the CMOS battery.
- Used the "Lenovo button" that this model has to reset the BIOS.
- Disconnected the battery and power charger, then pressed the power button for around a minute.
- Disconnected the hard drive.

Nothing seems to work.

The laptop was working perfectly fine before this BIOS firmware update.

Is there anything else I could try?

Answer (score 1):

There is a recovery procedure for recovering from a bad firmware update. You can create a recovery USB stick containing the firmware and instruct your machine to flash it via a special key combination. You will need a second fully functional computer to extract the firmware and create the recovery USB.

#### Procedure:

1. So, to be able to extract the bios file from the BIOS setup file, you need to download Inno Setup Unpacker from https://sourceforge.net/projects/innounp/
2. Then, extract innounp049.rar. You will get a file called innounp.exe
3. Put the BIOS file 6scn49ww.exe in the same folder with innounp.exe
4. Open cmd window and go to the location of the two files above
5. Type `innoup -x 6scn49ww.exe` to extract the bios files
6. You will have a new folder called {app}. Here, you will rename the file 6SCN49WW.CAP to BIOS.cap
7. Format the USB stick to FAT32
8. Copy the newly renamed BIOS.cap to the root of the USB stick. Safetly remove the stick.
9. Connect the charger to the laptop. The battery must be almost full.
10. Insert the USB stick
11. Hold Fn and R key pressed
12. Press power button to turn on the laptop (no need to hold power button, but keep hold on Fn and R keys)
13. You will hear some beeps. Now you can release the Fn + R keys. The BIOS is rewriting. It will restart several times.
14. Not sure if this matters but I used the USB port on the right.
15. Also don't know if it matters, but I used a USB 2.0 flash drive.

[Source](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-C-E-K-M-N-and-V-Series-Notebooks/BIOS-UPDATE-6scn42ww-FOR-MODEL-V330-15-IKB-FAILED/m-p/4495970?page=2#5043883)

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity I've added a description to the top.

Comment: I can't still accept your answer... I've tried with USB 3.0, 2.0, formatted in FAT, FAT32, from linux, from windows, on every USB port, 3 different USBs, starting the laptop with the lenovo button and I don't know what else. The laptop doesn't reboot in the process and it seems to read the USB, but no beep, black screen, this holding Fn+R for a minute.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity Go over each single step and confirm that you've executed it 100% correctly, use a different USB stick.

Comment: There's a difference, I can't find the file `6scn49ww`, the lenovo page though offers [this](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-v-series-laptops/v330-15ikb/downloads/ds501698-bios-update-for-windows-7-32-bit-64-bit-windows-10-64-bit-v330-15ikb-v330-15isk?category=BIOS%2FUEFI), I would think is the same.

Comment: I used three sticks, I've followed the steps several times and read the whole post you linked.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity looking at the [changelog of the BIOS update](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles/6scn54ww.txt), it seems that they made some changes to the "crisis function", which is supposed to handle the recovery. It might be possible that you are completely out of luck here. Try contacting the lenovo support. If they can't help you, your last chance would be to get a professional 3rd party shop to reflash your firmware with the help of some hardware.